# C - meaning of non zero adresses in nullspace

Tags: c, malloc

This is a linked list queue implementation.

This is my program

```
int  size(QueuePtr q)
{   
    QueuePtr temp = q->next;
    int size = 0;

    while(temp)
    {
        size++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return size;
}
```

where QueuePtr is defined like this

```
struct QueueElement 
{                       
    struct QueueElement *next;              
    int prio;                               
    DataPtr data;                       
}; 

typedef struct QueueElement *QueuePtr;
```

My program crashes when an adress is pointing to nullspace but isnt null!

```
Bad arg exception

  temp = 0xf00000000000000  (while is not aborted since temp != 0)
  temp = temp->next         (this line generates the exception)
```

My debugger said that I'm free(----) memory that has not been malloced. But that didnt help me much -

What does this adress mean? Can I simply change my while(something) statement?

Comment: if you don't initialize a variable then it can contain *anything*. A bad pointer will evaluate to true, so initialize the last next pointer to 0

Comment: In C, you should `#include <stddef.h>` and use `NULL` to test for null pointers, as the implementation may not actually use the value zero.  Try `while(NULL != temp)` instead.  Also, as ratchet freak says, make sure you initialise the `next` members of every new `QueueElement` to `NULL` when you create them.

Comment: @MikeofSST The implementation does not necessarily use the null *bit pattern* for `NULL`, but `0` is always a NULL pointer if used in pointer context.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: A bad pointer converted to boolean could still be equal to `yellow`, as far as the Standard is concerned. Once you hit UB, all sanity is gone.

Comment: @MikeofSST: All null pointers evaluate as false, and all pointers to objects /functions evaluate to true. You're not doing a `memcmp` here.

Comment: @MikeofSST: The *null pointer constant* is always 0-valued (6.3.2.3/3), and the `NULL` macro is set to the null pointer constant (either a naked `0`, or an expression like `(void *) 0`, or something like that).  The runtime null pointer *value* may be non-zero, but as far as your source code is concerned, 0 always represents a null pointer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't initialize the `next` pointers to 0 then they can contain *anything* including non-valid pointers.

In a Debug build uninitialized memory usually has a recognizable pattern like `0xfeeefeee` or `0xdeadbeef` just so it can be recognized as uninitialized.

To fix this you should set the next pointer to 0 explicitly when you create a node:

```
QueuePtr createNode(int prio, DataPtr data){
    QueuePtr node = (QueuePtr)malloc(sizeof(struct QueueElement));
    node->next = null;
    node->prio = prio;
    node-> data = data;
    return node;
}
```

Comment: Ye, codeLite on my mac didnt set my unitinialized pointers but my windows codeLite did. They are called 0xb44df00d :b thats when I found the bug ^^